# Marshal.PtrToStructure access violation

Tags: c#

can anyone see why it's failing ? If I replace "out IntPtr lpvObject" with "ref BITMAP lpvObject", I could get it to work that way. But I just can't see anything wrong with the code as it is.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Program
{
  class Core
  {
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]    
    public struct BITMAP
    {
        public Int32  bmType;
        public Int32  bmWidth;
        public Int32  bmHeight;
        public Int32  bmWidthBytes;
        public UInt16 bmPlanes;
        public UInt16 bmBitsPixel;
        public IntPtr bmBits;
    }


    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
      public static extern int GetObject ( IntPtr hgdiobj, int cbBuffer, out IntPtr lpvObject );


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Bitmap TestBmp = new Bitmap ( 10, 10 );
      BITMAP BitmapStruct = new BITMAP();
      IntPtr pBitmapStruct, pBitmapStructSave;
      int    Status;

      pBitmapStructSave = pBitmapStruct = Marshal.AllocHGlobal ( Marshal.SizeOf(BitmapStruct) );

      Status = GetObject ( TestBmp.GetHbitmap(), Marshal.SizeOf (BitmapStruct), out pBitmapStruct );

      Console.WriteLine ( "\nBytes returned is " + Status + ", buffer address = " + pBitmapStruct );

      try
      {
        BitmapStruct = (BITMAP) Marshal.PtrToStructure ( pBitmapStruct, typeof(BITMAP) );
      }
      catch ( Exception Ex )
      {
        Console.WriteLine ( Ex.Message );
      }

      Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pBitmapStructSave);
    }
  }
}
```

The output is:

> Bytes returned is 32, buffer address = 42949672960
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
>
> at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(IntPtr ptr, Type structureType)
>
> at Program.Core.Main(String[] args) in D:\data\Projects\Test\Test\Program.cs:line 41

Comment: `out IntPtr lpvObject` -> `IntPtr lpvObject`

Comment: Use int GetObject (IntPtr hgdiobj, int cbBuffer, out BITMAP lpobj).  Easy peasy.

Comment: Yes, it also works with ref BITMAP as I stated. The trouble with that is it takes extra processing when the function returns a null 3rd parameter. The simplest solution remains taking a pointer as an output. In any case, I needed to know that the IntPtr type is an implicit out. I would not have guessed it in a thousand years. Nor would I have found it from searching.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be because you're using the wrong signature?

*[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
static extern int GetObject(IntPtr hgdiobj, int cbBuffer, IntPtr lpvObject);*

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/GetObject.html

Also, *out* means that the value needs to be initializes within the method and that is probably not happening since you already have the *lpvObject* defined.

Comment: The API specification states an output 3rd parameter: _Out_ LPVOID  lpvObject. So the signature is fine. The program output indicates the out parameter is returned with a pointer value as expected.

Comment: OK, thanks. I removed "out" and it's working now. I have to go re-read how the out keyword is used.

Comment: @user118708 look at [the example useage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145119(v=vs.85).aspx), you need to pass in the address of a valid buffer. I don't know why it is marked as OUT in the documentation but it definatly needs a valid object passed in

Comment: It's an OUT because there are two success outcomes. First, when the buffer is filled. Second, when the buffer is too small and a null is returned for the pointer. I got confused because I didn't realise IntPtr is an out parameter by default in the context of p/invoke. I tried but failed to find any information on that. I imagine I have to be someone inside MS's inner circle to have access to that kind of info.